# How the I/O performance of legacy mainframes/minicomputers in different architectures is measured and benchmarked comparatively?

Tags: mainframe, architecture, minicomputers, io, server

Powerful in computing power, mainframes were irreplaceable thanks to the capability of processing numerous transactions rather than doing the math.

While computing power is measured in FLOPS and MIPS, how is I/O performance of  mainframes/minicomputers measured?

Legacy mainframes of which era had already outperformed average modern servers in x86 or ARM architectures?

Comment: Baud or bits (or bytes) per time unit?

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your assertion that legacy mainframes outperform modern servers?

Comment: @jwh20 [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/bit.listserv.ibm-main/c/dNYA27d5yHI/m/OlJSmwFVQOoJ) claims 1 million transactions per day on a S/390. [This page](https://www.omg.org/mda/mda_files/EDCubed_postgirot_bankstory.htm) claims S/390 support a service scalable from 2 million to 30 million transactions per day. To compare with, a windows web server may handle 1 million page views or 10 million PV with nginx. A MySQL node may handle 2000 TQS or more. That's close already.

Comment: Question: Is a "transaction" from the S/390 equivalent in complexity to a "web page view" in Windows or other modern OS?  My guess is, probably not.  IMHO 1M "transactions/day" is well below today's state-of-the-art.

Comment: @jwh20 No idea similar or not. I guess IIS may be the bottle neck in the case above, and switching to nginx would ease this, hence bottle neck moves somewhere else.

Comment: My point was that what we call a "transaction" today is much more complex than a "transaction" for an OS/390 system back in its day.  So you really cannot compare the two simply.

Comment: @jwh20 Yes and no. 1M transaction a day was what we could do on a mid range 1985 mainframe. THen again, the question is what a transaction is. After all, 1M read transactions which at maximum write some bytes in a log file, if at all, is vastly different from 1M write transactions which more often than not contain sub-transactions on remote systems. So no, comparing it to web pages which are mostly a matter of cache hit and some easy to speed up read are not what a credit card transaction would be.

Comment: Not FLOPS&MIPS - but Gibson Mix! http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/cpumix.htm

Comment: We measure I/O performance in [IOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS).

Comment: @Schezuk This https://www.sqlpipe.com/blog/postgresql-mariadb-performance claims between 50k and 100k transactions per minute on representative hardware in early 2022.

Comment: Also note that a lot of the inertia comes from the newer models being able to run all the existing software, just faster.  Typically as fast as you can afford.  It is usually much cheaper to modify tried and tested existing software instead of porting it to a new platform.

Answer (score 3):

> Powerful in computing power, mainframes were irreplaceable thanks to the capability of processing numerous transactions rather than doing the math.

True. At least when using a /360ish mainline. Those machines are direct descendants of punch card equipment, so it's all about how fast they process cards (or in modern terms transactions) which is directly related to their I/O rate.

This starts with already early models operating with one or more sub processors dedicated to I/O. In modern terms they are DMA processors. Processors as they do more than just a providing addressing when a byte/word is to be read, but manage multiple devices in parallel as well as multiple I/O for the same device without interaction with the main CPU. This of course including basic error handling as well. What we today know as a block device driver is almost complete hidden in hardware.

To handle a block the CPU just fills a parameter block with controller and device number a transfer address and read or write command and issues that instruction. The IOC will only return (with an interrupt) when the block is read, or a definitive error is reached. A bit like SCSI. In addition those commands can be chained,  so a single CPU command can perform multiple block reads, even across drives (*1), before returning.

A single IOC can have multiple channels that can operate in parallel - think of them as multiple DMA controllers - as well as multiplexing drives over the same channel.

Hardware wise a channel is always connected to a controller, which in turn is connected to the drives. The controller got own 'intelligence' as he's for example doing seeks on his own.

Depending on format this intelligence even goes further as it can do key searches depending on the format used. In this case a disk sector is not (only) prefixed by a track/sector number but a key field. When an application needs to retrieve a record, it simply forwards the key as part of a seek with a followed read. For practical purpose this is like not only having the block driver but as well basic data base handlers already in hardware - and outsourced to sub processors.

In addition to all of this comfort controllers could be connected to multiple channels and drives being attached to multiple controllers. Imagine a disk drive attached to two different SCSI controllers (*2), which in turn are attached to two different host interfaces. Doing so reduced congestion wherever possible.

Mainframe IO is about maximizing paralelizaton:

- Busy disks don't block access to other disks
- Busy controllers don't block access
- Any kind of I/O doesn't block the CPU

> While computing power is measured in FLOPS and MIPS, how is I/O performance of mainframes/minicomputers measured?

There is no easy measure. In fact, the peak data transfer rates, measured in MiB/s are not much higher as with (top end) computers/devices of the same time. That's simply defined by what a disk can deliver and what connector interface at that time actual technology allowed.

The real difference is about utilization. As it should be visible from above description, All effort in data processing mainframes go into paralellization to not only get peak rates, but sustained rates.

This philosophy even goes so far that single application may often run *slower* than on comparable minis, but in turn many of them run in parallel giving a higher over all performance. This goes well with transaction based operation. they are the perfect use case for this by being maximum parallel.

So if at all, transaction numbers may be a good performance criteria - but then again, this is extreme dependent on structure and type of transactions. Generations of engineers have spend countless hours to battle their measurements :))

> Legacy mainframes of which era had already outperformed average modern servers in x86 or ARM architectures?

This can not be said without giving some corner stone to measure against. Of course will modern ARM (or x86) systems outperform a 1970s mainframe in next to all specs (*3). Especially with modern disk systems and interface technology. Comparing to them is comparing apples with oranges.

The playfield has been levelled. Even more when ARM/x86 come in massive parallel configuration. If a socket provides 128 cores it doesn't matter that half of them are processing some bloated ... err complex ... I/O code and wait for drives to hand back requests.

On the other hand, modern mainframe hardware hasn't stopped evolving either. It's a tie hardware wise - so the difference is in software - and we all know how hard that is to quantify.

*Bottom line: Define what your criteria are, then one may look at developmend according to that criteria over time. Without it's a fruitless nerd game.*

---

*1 - Just hink how handy that would be for a RAID structure?

*2 - That is the real controller, the part nowadays integrated in an SCSI disk, not the host interface.

*3 - Lets set classic hardware like printers aside. Nothing beats a high end CDC chain printer (or modern high thruput laser). Then again, any micro based computing center of today would simply use the same printers as their mainframe counter part.

Comment: If you look at the typical modern server rack these days, if it is for a big business application, you will sometimes find actually surprisingly similar structures at play at the logical level - a few virtual or physical machines are in control of the flow, a lot of others actually act as coprocessors (some of them cater to block mode terminals, these days called web browsers, others preprocess network traffic, others abstract I/O (database servers)) even if they are "full" computers at a hardware level....

Comment: @rackandboneman Sounds like microservices?

Comment: @Schezuk or like a common model to host large web applications, with dedicated frontend, database, and heavy-lifting servers...

Comment: @rackandboneman well that's what was meant with the 128 core part. In the end, if the processors are many enough, it the advantage of speed, better management and dedicated hardware will narrow. Of course only if these systems again develop new methods of fast parallel communication otherwise all we do is adding another bottleneck.

Comment: A lot of the stuff we take for granted in an x86 based business datacenter setup in the 2010s and 2020s (massive SMP, robust virtualization, very fast networks, very dense hardware (blades..), GPU acceleration of non graphics code) was exotic, experimental or unavailable even in the early 2000s. A lot of "superiority of legacy mainframes" claims might actually have been carried over from that era...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a Burroughs supermini left running over a weekend to generate enough database TPM statistics to demonstrate compliance with performance requirements before it was shipped. I mention this because I don't know whether Burroughs had an SQL-based database, which would suggest less translation overhead etc.

I wonder what "a million transactions a day" really meant in the late 1960s or early 1970s? It certainly wouldn't have been "traditional" card-based batch work, since IBM was not exactly renowned for the speed of their card readers. It could possibly have been tape-to-tape payroll etc. at a bureau, but even that implies a veritable army of data preparation staff. And I'm not sure when the infrastructure surrounding SQL etc. databases got to the point that that level of traffic inside a single organisation was realistic.

But the real question is "what does legacy mean?". It would be reasonable to compare standard TPC-C performance between a 1970s-era mainframe or supermini and a single modern server, but far more difficult to do so after IBM (as a particular example) introduced their Parallel Sysplex architecture (clustered non-Single-System-Image mainframes) and "plumbed in" the capability to migrate workload and reroute communication paths: a degree of flexibility which I am not sure exists in modern kit.